# Using find command to set env vars in gitlab-ci

Tags: linux, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, exit-code, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to use the `find` command in linux to detect if some file types are present in the current directory in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` by doing the following:

```yaml
---
stages:
  - "discover"

file types:
  image: "alpine:latest"
  stage: "discover"
  script:
    - "set +e" # so the job won't fail when the exit code is not 0
    - "find -name '*.py' -exec ls '{}' + | grep ."
    - "echo \"PY=$?\" >> build.env"
    - "find -name '*.yml' -exec ls '{}' + | grep ."
    - "echo \"YML=$?\" >> build.env"
    - "find -name '*.yaml' -exec ls '{}' + | grep ."
    - "echo \"YAML=$?\" >> build.env"
    - "cat build.env" # returns: PY=0, YML=0, YAML=0
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: "build.env"
```

However, in the return of doing `cat build.env` inside the pipeline, I actually get:

```sh
cat build.env
PY=0
YML=0
YAML=0
```

Whereas, I don't actually have any `.yaml` files, I always use `.yml`, so this should return `YAML=1`.
If I execute the commands in linux myself, and not in the CI, it works as expected:

```sh
cat build.env
PY=0
YML=0
YAML=1
```

I am guessing there is something happening inside the gitlab pipeline somewhere, but to me, it looks like this should work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is all inside `"` quotes? Just `- find -name '*.yaml' -exec ls '{}' + | grep .`. Why are you using `ls` at all?

Comment: @KamilCuk `"` are just a habit I've had when building yaml.
I removed them all to test, but no difference. 
I also removed `-exec ls`, you're right, that wasn't needed. But yes, same problem still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```sh
    - "set +e -vx"
    - "PY=$(find -name '*.py' | grep .)"
    - |
      if [[ "${PY}" ]]; then
          PY=0
      else
          PY=1
      fi
```

It made it longer, but @KamilCuk's answer didn't quite satisfy.
But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it on the same line.

```
- find -name '*.py' | grep . ; echo PY=$? >> build.env
- find -name '*.yml' | grep . ; echo YML=$? >> build.env
- find -name '*.yaml' | grep . ; echo YAML=$? >> build.env
```

I think I would do:

```
- find -name '*.py' | wc -l | sed 's/^/PY=/' >> build.env
- find -name '*.yml' | wc -l | sed 's/^/YML=/' >> build.env
- find -name '*.yaml' | wc -l | sed 's/^/YAML=/' >> build.env
```

or maybe

```
- ( printf PY=; find -name '*.py' | wc -l ) >> build.env
```